# general purpose Comparator for a TreeMap<Object, T>?

Tags: java, object, tree, comparator

I need `TreeMap<Object, HGHandle>` but my objects are neither Comparable nor is there a common `Comparator<Object>`.

The order in the Tree beeing only relevant for the tree itself, is there ANY general Comparator that I could use for the Tree?

Info:
I want to add a trivial caching mechanism of some database-like library, specialized for bulk import. Since it is a very memory-consuming task, I prefer to use a Tree-based Map over HashMap, so the BulkImportCache becomes more space efficient and can grow and shrink as required.

Comment: So you prefer an `O(nlgn)` put time as opposed to an `O(1)` put time? This seems a _bad_ choice for bulk import...

Comment: @ Boris the Spider: I'm still investigating. It's not only about speed but also a matter of memory. Also I believe it is O(lgn) not O(n ln n). Also, keep in mind, that HashMaps doesn't have O(1) when it has to grow all the time. You may say, ok, just put a sufficiently large start size. But if it grows beyond that, the underlying HashTable uses immediately much more space.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to use a `TreeMap` you MUST be able to compare the instances that you intend to store in the `Map`. You might have a comparator that knows the different types of object that can be stored in the map and delegates to type-specific comparators based on type. But any way you slice it, you MUST provide a comparison mechanism and one DOES NOT exist for non-`Comparable` objects.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Code updated.

This may work, but using a checksum algo requires objects to be not mutated. Trying to find a decent way to test.

```
import  org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

class HashCodeComparator implements Comparator<Object>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        final int dif = o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode();
        if (dif == 0)
                if(o1.equals(o2))
                    return 0;
                else
                    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(o1) - HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(o2);
        else
            return dif;
    }
```

Comment: This **will not work**. Objects that are **not** equals can (and will) have the same hashcode. You will end up with a cache the (seemingly) randomly returns the wrong value.

Comment: This will not work because two non-equal object can have equal hash codes.

Comment: No because if `compare(a,b)` returns `-1`, then `compare(b,a)` must return `1`. In your implementation, both return `-1`.

Comment: @JohnB updated once more. Could it work when using the difference of the checksums of some other hashing algo in the nested else branch? see code. I'm thinking on how to test this in a general way...

Comment: No because your two elements could be non-equal and the `HashCodeBuilder` could return the same value for them. No different than if you had just compared their hash codes using `hashCode`

Comment: @JohnB agreed that this is may be possible, but wouldn't it be extremely, negligeable unlikely to have accidental hashCode collisions twice for two different ways of calculating them? Ok: if instead of HashCodeBuilder i'd serialize and make strong checksums, then it should work?

Comment: No, anytime you convert to an int you will get collisions.

Comment: @JohnB with strong I meant something like 128 or more bits. Then, it should work?